# how to increase backgroundTimeRemaining

Tags: iphone

how to increase backgroundTimeRemaining so because of that my application will get remain in background ,if you have any other way to run program in background  please tell me ....
other wise i want my application wake after call connected or disconnected in background ....
without coming it on foreground ....

suggestion appreciated ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *fortunately* not possible.

Comment: I guess the the answer is *no*.

Answer (score 1):

**[Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)**

Specifically the section entitled Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks

Comment: He asked how to increase the background execution, not stating the obvious of what he already did.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Push notifications